# How to animate background color of a DataGrid row once when mouse over?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that have some rows on it. When new rows are added, I want to set background to some bright value to show users that the rows are newly added. When users hover a mouse on a row, animate it back to normal color (transparent).

An example model

```
public class Package
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOversea { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOfArrival { get; set; }
}
```

For now, all I can do is to animate a color from current to transparent.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="ForestGreen"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGridRow.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                    Duration="00:00:02"
                                    To="Transparent"
                                    />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But I want to trigger this animation only once if that row has `IsOversea == true`.

And if possible, I also want to bind starting background color to a property too. Like red if the package has been waiting for delivery for more than 1 month, Yellow if more than 1 week and Green with a day.

Comment: Did you consider implementing the animation programmatically?

Comment: Oh. Maybe all I have to do is to create an animation and trigger it once in C#. Let me try and keep you updated. But I want to respect MVVM design also.

Comment: MVVM isn't about eliminating code from the views. It's about separation of concerns.

Comment: Thank you. I successfully created the behavior I want. But it's hurts performance too much. With row virtualization, animation doesn't work correctly. The animation overflows onto the next item as I scroll fast.